# Open lid to wakeup the system, get white screen

Tags: power-management, suspend

I got a new Dell M3800 laptop and I use gentoo+fvwm

In /etc/acpi/lid.sh , I use

echo -n mem >/sys/power/state

to let the system sleep when the lid is closed.

The problem is when I open the lid, I got a white screen. I need to do

ctrl+alt+F1 to go the console then ctrl+alt+F7 to go back to fvwm to eliminate the white screen.

I check the demesg and I found the following errors

[ 2779.734885] pciehp 0000:00:1c.0:pcie04: Link Training Error occurs

[ 2779.734886] pciehp 0000:00:1c.0:pcie04: Failed to check link status

[ 2779.734986] dpm_run_callback(): pnp_bus_resume+0x0/0xa0 returns -19

[ 2779.734987] PM: Device 00:08 failed to resume: error -19

[ 2779.782972] tpm_tis 00:0c: TPM is disabled/deactivated (0x6)

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve the problems. Thanks.

Comment: The problem was solved by installing an older or a new version of nvidia driver.